# Outlook: Changing server settings but not email address

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm currently switching email provider for a client of mine - they are sticking with the same email address but the email host is changing.

They currently use Outlook (2010 I think) and fetch using POP3.

As POP is storing the emails locally, do I just need to change the settings in Outlook once the provider has been switched over? I assume as the emails are stored locally, it will just start fetching from the new location and all of the old emails will stay in tact?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: By Email provider do you mean they have a domain like joebloggs.com and they are moving that from one domain hosting company to another therefore the Emails will be switching to the new hosting companies service as well?

Comment: Yep - exactly that.

Comment: It's been a while since I've touched anything POP3 related so I wont 'answer' as I'm not 100% certain however my thoughts are you can simply change the details in the Mail account to the new Incoming and Outgoing Server addresses with any changes to the user authentication and it will not touch the locally stored Emails in that account just update the account to the new hosting services details. What I would do is create a test account put a few Emails in it and test moving it over to the new service before you perform this on a real user.